# Assign value to new df column with condition and use bigger value if there's no excatly matching value

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe, merge

Assume we have two DataFrames:

DF1:

```
spec   u_g    target
G1     4.8    0.88
G2     2.1    0.76
WG2    1.4    0.71
WG2    1.2    0.68
WG2    1.0    0.52
WG3    0.8    0.65
WG3    0.7    0.53
SWG3   0.7    0.31
```

DF2:

```
id  type     u_g_1    
1   WG2      1.4 
2   WG2      1.4
3   WG2      1.0
4   G1       4.8
5   G1       4.9
6   G2       2.1
7   SWG3     0.7
8   WG3      0.8
9   WG3      0.7
10  WG2      1.1
11  nan      0
```

For every row in DF2 I'd like to look up if the type match with an entry in DF1, if yes, I'd like to look if there is an entry in DF1 with the corresponding value u_g_1 == u_g, if yes, choose the target value and assign this to DF2.
**If not, assign the next bigger value in u_g for the same type to the new 'target' column.**

DF2_modified:

```
id  type     u_g_1   u_g   target   
1   WG2      1.4     1.4   0.71 
2   WG2      1.4     1.4   0.71
3   WG2      1.0     1.0   0.52
4   G1       4.8     4.8   0.88
5   G1       4.9     4.8   0.88
6   G2       2.1     2.1   0.76
7   SWG3     0.7     0.7   0.31
8   WG3      0.8     0.8   0.65
9   WG3      0.7     0.7   0.53
10  WG2      1.1     1.2   0.68
11  nan      0       nan   nan
```

I tried it with

```
df2.merge(df1, left_on=['type', 'u_g_1'], right_on=['spec', 'u_g'], how='left')
```

This gives me target-values where type == spec and u_g_1 == u_g, but not for the ones where there is no value u_g in u_g_1. In this case I'd like to assign the next bigger value from u_g

Someone can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) with [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and last [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df = (pd.merge_asof(df2.sort_values('u_g_1'), 
                    df1.sort_values('u_g'), 
                    left_on='u_g_1', 
                    left_by='type', 
                    right_on='u_g', 
                    right_by='spec')
      .sort_values('id', ignore_index=True))
print (df)
    id  type  u_g_1  spec  u_g  target
0    1   WG2    1.4   WG2  1.4    0.71
1    2   WG2    1.4   WG2  1.4    0.71
2    3   WG2    1.0   WG2  1.0    0.52
3    4    G1    4.8    G1  4.8    0.88
4    5    G1    4.9    G1  4.8    0.88
5    6    G2    2.1    G2  2.1    0.76
6    7  SWG3    0.7  SWG3  0.7    0.31
7    8   WG3    0.8   WG3  0.8    0.65
8    9   WG3    0.7   WG3  0.7    0.53
9   10   WG2    1.1   WG2  1.0    0.52
10  11   NaN    0.0   NaN  NaN     NaN
```

EDIT: Same solution with changed default `direction='backward'` to `direction='forward'`:

```
df = (pd.merge_asof(df2.sort_values('u_g_1'), 
                    df1.sort_values('u_g'), 
                    left_on='u_g_1', 
                    left_by='type', 
                    right_on='u_g', 
                    right_by='spec',
                    direction='forward')
      .sort_values('id', ignore_index=True))
print (df)
    id  type  u_g_1  spec  u_g  target
0    1   WG2    1.4   WG2  1.4    0.71
1    2   WG2    1.4   WG2  1.4    0.71
2    3   WG2    1.0   WG2  1.0    0.52
3    4    G1    4.8    G1  4.8    0.88 
4    5    G1    4.9   NaN  NaN     NaN <- 4.9 is greater like 4.8 so NaN
5    6    G2    2.1    G2  2.1    0.76
6    7  SWG3    0.7  SWG3  0.7    0.31
7    8   WG3    0.8   WG3  0.8    0.65
8    9   WG3    0.7   WG3  0.7    0.53
9   10   WG2    1.1   WG2  1.2    0.68 <- 1.1 is less like 1.1 so match
10  11   NaN    0.0   NaN  NaN     NaN
```

Another idea with `direction='nearest'`:

```
df = (pd.merge_asof(df2.sort_values('u_g_1'), 
                    df1.sort_values('u_g'), 
                    left_on='u_g_1', 
                    left_by='type', 
                    right_on='u_g', 
                    right_by='spec',
                    direction='nearest')

      .sort_values('id', ignore_index=True))
print (df)
    id  type  u_g_1  spec  u_g  target
0    1   WG2    1.4   WG2  1.4    0.71
1    2   WG2    1.4   WG2  1.4    0.71
2    3   WG2    1.0   WG2  1.0    0.52
3    4    G1    4.8    G1  4.8    0.88
4    5    G1    4.9    G1  4.8    0.88
5    6    G2    2.1    G2  2.1    0.76
6    7  SWG3    0.7  SWG3  0.7    0.31
7    8   WG3    0.8   WG3  0.8    0.65
8    9   WG3    0.7   WG3  0.7    0.53
9   10   WG2    1.1   WG2  1.2    0.68
10  11   NaN    0.0   NaN  NaN     NaN
```

EDIT2: First is used `direction='forward'` and then replaced missing values by `direction='backward'`:

```
df0 = (pd.merge_asof(df2.sort_values('u_g_1'), 
                    df1.sort_values('u_g'), 
                    left_on='u_g_1', 
                    left_by='type', 
                    right_on='u_g', 
                    right_by='spec').set_index('id'))
print (df0)
    type  u_g_1  spec  u_g  target
id                                
11   NaN    0.0   NaN  NaN     NaN
7   SWG3    0.7  SWG3  0.7    0.31
9    WG3    0.7   WG3  0.7    0.53
8    WG3    0.8   WG3  0.8    0.65
3    WG2    1.0   WG2  1.0    0.52
10   WG2    1.1   WG2  1.0    0.52
1    WG2    1.4   WG2  1.4    0.71
2    WG2    1.4   WG2  1.4    0.71
6     G2    2.1    G2  2.1    0.76
4     G1    4.8    G1  4.8    0.88
5     G1    4.9    G1  4.8    0.88
```

---

```
df = (pd.merge_asof(df2.sort_values('u_g_1'), 
                    df1.sort_values('u_g'), 
                    left_on='u_g_1', 
                    left_by='type', 
                    right_on='u_g', 
                    right_by='spec',
                    direction='forward')
      .set_index('id')
      .combine_first(df0)
      .sort_index()
      .reset_index()
      )
print (df)
    id  type  u_g_1  spec  u_g  target
0    1   WG2    1.4   WG2  1.4    0.71
1    2   WG2    1.4   WG2  1.4    0.71
2    3   WG2    1.0   WG2  1.0    0.52
3    4    G1    4.8    G1  4.8    0.88
4    5    G1    4.9    G1  4.8    0.88
5    6    G2    2.1    G2  2.1    0.76
6    7  SWG3    0.7  SWG3  0.7    0.31
7    8   WG3    0.8   WG3  0.8    0.65
8    9   WG3    0.7   WG3  0.7    0.53
9   10   WG2    1.1   WG2  1.2    0.68
10  11   NaN    0.0   NaN  NaN     NaN
```

Comment: This is very close to what i was looking for, but e.g. for WG2 | 1.1, I get WG2 | 1.0 | 0.52, instead of WG2 | 1.2 | 0.68

Comment: Is it possible to use direction='forward' first, if this results in NaN, then use direction='backward'??

Comment: I tried nearest, but nearest results in a missmatch for many rows :( Is there a way to perform direction = 'foreward' first and then overwrite the NaNs in a next step with direction = 'backward'?

Comment: @Aukru - Answer was edited again fior repalced all NaNs if exist non NaN values in `df0`